# Vectorizing groups of function calls

Tags: function, macros, julia, vectorization, metaprogramming

I am trying to write a functionality, (using macro, generated function or something), that effectively vectorizes Julia function calls to functions that I've written. Basically, I'm trying to write my own version of the @. macro, but instead, I'd like it to accept functions instead of a for loop--- if I understand this correctly. Here are some documents that I've read on the subject:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/broadcast.jl

https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/index.html#Code-Generation-1

Here is my preliminary toy example that I'm working with to achieve such a functionality:

```
function add!(v_add::Vector{Float64}, a_add::Float64, j::Int64)
  v_add[j] = v_add[j]+a_add
end

function add!(v_add::Vector{Float64}, a_add::Float64)
  for j in 1:length(v_add)
    v_add[j] = v_add[j]+a_add
  end
end

macro vectorize(args)
  print("\n****************** args\n")
  print(args)
  print("\n******************\n")
  e = :(:call,
    $args[1],
    $args[2],
    $args[3])
  print("\n****************** expression\n")
  show(e)
  print(e)
  print("\n******************\n")
  return e
end

function test!(v_test, a_test)
  # # Traverse vector twice
  # add!(v_test, a_test)
  # add!(v_test, a_test)
  # Traverse vector once
  args = [
  add!, v_test, a_test,
  add!, v_test, a_test
  ]
  e = @vectorize(args)
  # eval(e) # Next step
end

v_main = Vector([Float64(i) for i in 1:3])
a_main = Float64(2.0)
print("\n",v_main, "\n")
Main.test!(v_main, a_main)
print("\n",v_main, "\n")
```

The problem I'm having so far is that I can't even get the de-vectorized version running using macros. This example results in the LoadError: UndefVarError: args not defined. I would definitely appreciate any help in getting this script working as expected (input is [1, 2, 3], and output should be [5, 6, 7]).

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Update**

More concretely, given the following defined functions:

```
function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64)
  for j in 1:length(v)
    v[j]+= a
  end
end
function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64, j::Int64)
  v[j]+= a
end
```

I would like to be able to use a macro to convert the following lines of code:

```
v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
a = 1
b = 2
@vectorize_I_would_like_to_define(
# I don't know the exact form that the args to this macro should take.
add!(v, a),
add!(v, b)
)
```

To generate code that is compiled like this:

```
v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
a = 1
b = 2
for j in 1:length(v)
  add!(v, a, j)
  add!(v, b, j)
end
```

My goal is to write code that requires a single memory traversal.

Even better, if I could generate code that looks like this at compile time:

```
v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
a = 1
b = 2
for j in 1:length(v)
  v[j]+= a # taken from add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64, j::Int64)
  v[j]+= b # taken from add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64, j::Int64)
end
```

But I'm not sure if this is as feasable for more complex cases that I'm considering compared to this toy example.

** Update 2**

Here is a MWE of @Bogumił Kamiński's solution---except that I've moved the macro call into a function, so now it doesn't work because it complains that `v_test` is not defined.

```
macro vectorize(args...)
    expr = :()
    for arg in args
        a = deepcopy(arg) # for safety in case arg is also used somewhere else
        push!(a.args, :j)
        expr = :($expr; $a)
    end
    quote
        for j in 1:length(v)
            $expr
        end
    end
end

function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64)
  for j in 1:length(v)
    v[j]+= a
  end
end

function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64, j::Int64)
  v[j]+= a
end

v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
a = 1.0
b = 2.0

function test!(v_test, a_test, b_test)
  @vectorize(
  add!(v_test, a_test),
  add!(v_test, b_test)
  )
end

test!(v, a, b)
```

Comment: I am not 100% clear what you want to achieve. Could you please give a description of an input and expected processing workflow?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, I added a more concrete example of the functionality that I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: EDIT and EDIT 2 in my answer work with your example (I leave both of them as I think it is helpful to analyze the difference between them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
macro vectorize(args...)
    expr = :()
    for arg in args
        a = deepcopy(arg) # for safety in case arg is also used somewhere else
        push!(a.args, :j)
        expr = :($expr; $a)
    end
    quote
        for j in 1:length(v)
            $expr
        end
    end
end
```

and now

```
function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64)
  for j in 1:length(v)
    v[j]+= a
  end
end

function add!(v::Vector{Float64}, a::Float64, j::Int64)
  v[j]+= a
end

v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
a = 1.0
b = 2.0

@vectorize(add!(v, a), add!(v, b))
```

Note that I have changed `a` and `b` definitions as your `add!` required `Float64` as a second argument.

EDIT: If you want to use this macro inside a function the simplest thing to do is to `esc` its whole return value:

```
macro vectorize(args...)
    expr = :()
    for arg in args
        a = deepcopy(arg) # for safety in case arg is also used somewhere else
        push!(a.args, :j)
        expr = :($expr; $a)
    end
    esc(quote
        for j in 1:length(v)
            $expr
        end
    end)
end
```

Then you can define e.g.:

```
function f()
    v = [Float64(j) for j in 1:10]
    a = 1.0
    b = 2.0
    @vectorize(add!(v, a), add!(v, b))
    v
end
```

and run `f()` to get the same result as above in global scope.

EDIT 2: I just realized that actually I have to sanitize `j` as otherwise the following code will fail:

```
test!(v_test, j, b_test) =
    @vectorize(add!(v_test, j), add!(v_test, b_test))
```

Here is how you should do it:

```
macro vectorize(args...)
    expr = :()
    j = gensym()
    for arg in args
        a = deepcopy(arg) # for safety in case arg is also used somewhere else
        push!(a.args, j)
        expr = :($expr; $a)
    end
    esc(quote
        for $j in 1:length(v)
            $expr
        end
    end)
end
```

As you can see developing macros is a non-obvious task (hopefully the final recipe is bug-free :)).

EDIT 3: Here is the code that correctly handles `length`. Also now in each expression actually you can pass a different value as a first argument (so you can independently process different vectors). If you do want to process the same vector check is `a.args[2]` is always the same symbol:

```
macro vectorize(args...)
    expr = :()
    j = gensym()
    for arg in args
        a = deepcopy(arg) # for safety in case arg is also used somewhere else
        var = a.args[2]
        push!(a.args, j)
        q = quote
            for $j in 1:length($var)
                $a
            end
        end
        expr = :($expr; $q)
    end
    esc(expr)
end
```

Comment: This is precisely what I need, except that I need the macro called within a function. I'll add a version of what I mean to the question.

Comment: I have added an example how to make all variables be resolved in macro call environment (including `j` - but in this case it is not a problem as `j` is guaranteed to be local to the `for` loop anyway and will not leak out). In a more complex situation you might have to be more careful and escape out only the variables that need to be resolved in macro call environment.

Comment: Actually `j` should be sanitized - see my EDIT 2. Your example works cleanly now.

Comment: This is close enough. The only thing that I would argue looks like is being cheated (which I suspect required some careful attention anyway) is the `length(v)` statement, which seems to use the scope for which `v` is defined. But I at least have an idea how this can be circumvented. Thanks!

Comment: And yes, developing macros does seem a bit non-obvious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have forgotten about `length(v)` - you are right you have to handle this. You should check if in all `args` `v` is the same symbol (because in general someone might call your macro incorrectly and pass different vectors in its consecutive argments) and if yes extract it and use in `length` call.

Comment: Ah, nice, this looks great and I think it’s helping me understand how to manipulate the expressions too. Thank you for all of your help! Also, is there a way that you can incline this function call (which I suspect is defined at a.args[1])?

Comment: yes `a.args[1]` is a `Symbol` that is a name of the function and you can change it to something else. If this name is escaped via `esc` then the symbol will be resolved in macro call environment. If it is not escaped then the symbol will be resolved in lexical scope of the macro.

Comment: Just to note, the version in EDIT 3 ends up resulting in multiple loops, which kind of defeats the purpose of using the macro. But if the sizes could be checked, then some modified form of this version could be used to group vectors of equal sizes.

Comment: This is easily changed - as you note. I did multiple loops on purpose to allow for possibility of varying size of the vector.